# Securing ManageSieve Dovecot plugin

Tags: email, dovecot

I've recently setup and configured dovecot and roundcube with managesieve and have been able to configure sieve through the roundcube plugin successfully.

I've noticed that there is a Thunderbird plugin for managesieve and am wondering if it is commonplace/secure to open the managesiieve port (4190) for external management?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Dovecot's `managesieve` is always used SSL/TLS and authorization if `ssl = yes` configured in the global options. If so you can see `STARTTLS` if connected manually via `telnet localhost 4190`.